# SQL: How can i use Union with count with 2 different types of data

Tags: mysql, sql-server, algorithm

The SQL code below gives me a overview of my customers and the orders they have done in december of the year 2015. I want to do this with UNION.

```
select k.klantnr, k.naam, count(b.bestelnr) as 'aantal bestellingen'
 from klant k LEFT JOIN bestelling b on k.klantnr = b.klantnr and Year (b.besteldatum) = 2015 and Month(b.besteldatum) = 12
 group by k.klantnr, k.naam
```

i already tried:

```
select klantnr from klant
union
select klantnr, count(*) from bestelling
where Year(besteldatum) = 2015 and Month(besteldatum) = 12
group by klantnr
```

obviously not working giving me this error: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

when i searched on google i found the next query:

```
select tem.klantnr, count(*) 
from(select klantnr from klant
union
select klantnr from bestelling where Year(besteldatum) = 2015 and Month(besteldatum) = 12) as tem
group by klantnr
```

not giving me the order count per customer.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server, which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this with `UNION`? What sort of output are you looking for? (Please provide sample data and expected output)

Comment: I don't think you need an union but a left join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
select k.klantnr, k.naam, orders.cnt as 'aantal bestellingen'
    from klant k
    outer apply (
                    select count(*) 
                      from bestelling 
                      where klantnr = k.klantnr 
                        and Year(besteldatum) = 2015 
                        and Month(besteldatum) = 12
                 ) as orders(cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all your customers and the number of orders in the specified month?

You can use outer apply as Ruslan proposed or left join.

```
select k.klantnr,coalesce(count(b.klantnr),0) as 'aantal bestellingen'
from klant k
left join bestelling b on k.klantnr = b.klantnr and Year(besteldatum) = 2015 and Month(besteldatum) = 12)
group by klantnr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need UNION, and you can handle the output, here's some SQLi style query :D

```
select klantnr, null from klant union
select klantnr, count(*) from bestelling
    where Year(besteldatum) = 2015
    and Month(besteldatum) = 12 group by klantnr
```